# How to override vendor packages with local src in dep (for local development)

Tags: go, dep

Pseudo project setup:

- $GOPATH/src/github.com/foo/common-libs
- $GOPATH/src/github.com/foo/my-project (has a dependency on common-libs managed by dep, copy in /vendor directory

Can't find a way to edit *common-libs* locally (i.e. in /src) and have those changes immediately reflected in *my-project*. The project /vendor file always has priority over that in $GOPATH.

Instead every time I need to push the *common-libs* changes to Github then run `dep ensure -update` in *my-project* -- which is really slow and annoying.

Tried (unsuccessfully):

1. Ignoring local /vendor in Gopkg.toml using `ignored = ["github.com/foo/common-libs*"]`, but throws a compilation error: `cannot use &amount (type *"github.com/foo/my-project/vendor/github.com/shopspring/decimal".Decimal) as type *"github.com/foo/common-libs/vendor/github.com/shopspring/decimal".Decimal in field value`)
2. Manually deleting *common-libs* from the /vendor directory of *my-project* (temporarily) -- but this leads to the same compilation error as #1 (and is annoying because running `dep ensure` adds the deleted folder back to the vendor folder).
3. Manually editing *common-libs* in /vendor (temporarily), which works -- but I lose static code analysis and I have to copy the changes to the actual *common-libs* projects afterwards.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What kinds of runtime faults for #2? This sounds like a bug in your code (or a library), and not the fault of the approach.

Comment: @Flimzy deps that depend on a different version of the same package might fail when using the GOPATH version, methinks

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: But that would usually manifest as a compilation failure. The OP mentions runtime failures.

Comment: @Flimzy Ah, missed that bit, fair point... probably time to read up on delve for the OP

Comment: My bad, actually a compilation error -- updated the question with near-exact error message.